# How to pass argument to controller with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I am passing  var argurmrnt to controller like this

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_profile', array('var' => $profile->getId())));
```

THis is my controller

```
/**


         * @Route("/profile", name="user_profile")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function ProfileAction($var)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

But i keep getting error

> Controller "xxxx\Controller\UserController::ProfileAction()" requires
>   that you provide a value for the "$var" argument (because there is no
>   default value or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to add placeholder to your route, according to [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)

```
    /**
     * @Route("/profile/{var}", name="user_profile")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function ProfileAction($var)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```